# I am facing the issue in the Inapp-purchse when i am create it show in draft

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am facing the issues of creating inappPurchase it shows in draft soo Please give me proper solution

creating inappPurchase it shows in draft soo it should be ready for sale soo tell where is the problem in my inapp-purchase setup or in any tax or agrements of client setup